# How to make sure data.table uses GForce

Tags: r, data.table

I'm running the following code with data.table and I'd like to understand a bit better what is the condition of triggering GForce

```
DT = data.table(date = rep(seq(Sys.Date(), by = "-1 day", length.out = 1000), 10),
                x    = runif(10000),
                id   = rep(1:10, each = 1000))
```

For the case below I can see it working:

```
DT[, .(max(x), min(x), mean(x)), by = id, verbose = T]

Detected that j uses these columns: x 
Finding groups using forderv ... 0 sec
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0 sec
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(max(x), min(x), mean(x))'
GForce optimized j to 'list(gmax(x), gmin(x), gmean(x))'
Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 0 secs
```

But for my use case it is not

```
window1 <- Sys.Date() - 50
window2 <- Sys.Date() - 150
window3 <- Sys.Date() - 550

DT[, .(max(x[date > Sys.Date() - 50]), max(x[date > Sys.Date() - 150]), 
       max(x[date > Sys.Date() - 550])), by = id, verbose = T]

Detected that j uses these columns: x,date 
Finding groups using forderv ... 0 sec
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0 sec
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(max(x[date > Sys.Date() - 50]), max(x[date > Sys.Date() - 150]), max(x[date > Sys.Date() - 550]))'
GForce is on, left j unchanged
Old mean optimization is on, left j unchanged.
Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ...
  memcpy contiguous groups took 0.000s for 10 groups
  eval(j) took 0.005s for 10 calls
0.005 secs
```

The only thing that comes to my mind is the fact that each vector in max functions has different length.

Comment: The function argument must be a simple column. In this case, it’s achievable with a non equi join, but I think it would be easier to illustrate that if you made a reproducible example.

Comment: I've added test DT.

Answer (score 2):

I'd do a non-equi join:

```
# convert to IDate for speed
DT[, date := as.IDate(date)]

mDT = CJ(id = unique(DT$id), days_ago = c(50L, 150L, 550L))
mDT[, date_dn := as.IDate(Sys.Date()) - days_ago]

res = DT[mDT, on=.(id, date > date_dn), .(
  days_ago = first(days_ago), 
  m = mean(x)
), by=.EACHI, verbose=TRUE]
```

This prints out...

```
Non-equi join operators detected ... 
  forder took ... 0 secs
  Generating group lengths ... done in 0 secs
  Generating non-equi group ids ... done in 0.01 secs
  Found 1 non-equi group(s) ...
Starting bmerge ...done in 0 secs
Detected that j uses these columns: days_ago,x 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(first(days_ago), mean(x))'
Old mean optimization changed j from 'list(first(days_ago), mean(x))' to 'list(first(days_ago), .External(Cfastmean, x, FALSE))'
Making each group and running j (GForce FALSE) ... 
  collecting discontiguous groups took 0.000s for 30 groups
  eval(j) took 0.000s for 30 calls
0 secs
```

So for some reason this uses another form of optimization instead of GForce.

The result looks like...

```
    id       date days_ago         m
 1:  1 2017-12-19       50 0.4435722
 2:  1 2017-09-10      150 0.4842963
 3:  1 2016-08-06      550 0.4775890
 4:  2 2017-12-19       50 0.4838715
 5:  2 2017-09-10      150 0.5150688
 6:  2 2016-08-06      550 0.5141174
 7:  3 2017-12-19       50 0.4804182
 8:  3 2017-09-10      150 0.4910027
 9:  3 2016-08-06      550 0.4901343
10:  4 2017-12-19       50 0.4644922
11:  4 2017-09-10      150 0.4902132
12:  4 2016-08-06      550 0.4810129
13:  5 2017-12-19       50 0.4666715
14:  5 2017-09-10      150 0.5193629
15:  5 2016-08-06      550 0.4850173
16:  6 2017-12-19       50 0.5318109
17:  6 2017-09-10      150 0.5481641
18:  6 2016-08-06      550 0.5216787
19:  7 2017-12-19       50 0.4500243
20:  7 2017-09-10      150 0.4915983
21:  7 2016-08-06      550 0.5055563
22:  8 2017-12-19       50 0.4958809
23:  8 2017-09-10      150 0.4915432
24:  8 2016-08-06      550 0.4981277
25:  9 2017-12-19       50 0.5833083
26:  9 2017-09-10      150 0.5160464
27:  9 2016-08-06      550 0.5091702
28: 10 2017-12-19       50 0.4946466
29: 10 2017-09-10      150 0.4798743
30: 10 2016-08-06      550 0.5030687
    id       date days_ago         m
```

As far as I know, optimization of this sort only kicks in when the argument to the function (`mean` here) is a simple column like `x`, rather than an expression like `x[date > Sys.Date() - 50]`.

Comment: I think because you also calls first here it doesn't use GForce.

Comment: @kismsu I also tried it without and saw the same thing. Fyi, `first` is also optimized by GForce. Extending your example... `DT[, .(max(x), min(x), mean(x), first(x)), by = id, verbose = T]`

Answer (score 0):

I've run the solution suggested by @Frank and got the following

```
DT[, date := as.IDate(date)]

mDT = CJ(id = unique(DT$id), days_ago = c(50L, 150L, 550L))
mDT[, date_dn := as.IDate(Sys.Date()) - days_ago]

cDT <- copy(DT) # To make sure we run different methods on different datasets

window1 <- Sys.Date() - 50
window2 <- Sys.Date() - 150
window3 <- Sys.Date() - 550

microbenchmark(
    cDT[mDT, on=.(id, date > date_dn), .(days_ago = first(days_ago), m = mean(x)), by=.EACHI],
    DT[, .(mean(x[date > window1]), mean(x[date > window2]), mean(x[date > window3])), by = id]
)

Unit: microseconds

expr      
cDT[mDT, on = .(id, date > date_dn), .(days_ago = first(days_ago), m = mean(x)), by = .EACHI] 
DT[, .(mean(x[date > window1]), mean(x[date > window2]), mean(x[date > window3])), by = id]  
min       lq     mean      median       uq      max neval cld
822.451 1462.756 1708.083  2481.601 2875.785 4459.506   100   b
1948.851 2313.842 2626.432 1565.562 1710.693 8717.868   100  a
```

I wouldn't be surprised if join is more costly then mean

Comment: The creation of `mDT` is probably also costly. Btw, one other approach would be to take cumulative mean and then filter to the dates of interest.

Comment: I doubt that this is quick, to many calculations you don't use at the end

Answer (score 0):

Was looking for how to force GForce to turn on and came across this OP.

`mtd3` contains a way to turn GForce on for this particular OP.  But it is still not faster than the OP's method.

```
mtd1 <- function() {
    mDT = CJ(id = unique(DT1$id), days_ago = c(50L, 150L, 550L))
    mDT[, date_dn := as.IDate(Sys.Date()) - days_ago]

    res = DT1[mDT, on=.(id, date > date_dn), .(
        days_ago = first(days_ago), 
        m = mean(x)
    ), by=.EACHI]   
}

mtd2 <- function() {
    DT2[, .(
            max(x[date > window1]), 
            max(x[date > window2]), 
            max(x[date > window3])
        ), by = id]
}

mtd3 <- function() {
    #Reduce(function(x, y) x[y, on="id"], 
       lapply(c(window1, window2, window3),
           function(d) DT3[date > d, .(max(x)), by = id, verbose=T])
    #)
}

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(mtd1(), mtd2(), mtd3(), times=1L)
```

mtd3() prints out:

```
i clause present and columns used in by detected, only these subset: id 
Detected that j uses these columns: x 
Finding groups using forderv ... 0.000sec 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000sec 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(max(x))'
GForce optimized j to 'list(gmax(x))'
Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 0.000sec 
i clause present and columns used in by detected, only these subset: id 
Detected that j uses these columns: x 
Finding groups using forderv ... 0.000sec 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000sec 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(max(x))'
GForce optimized j to 'list(gmax(x))'
Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 0.030sec 
i clause present and columns used in by detected, only these subset: id 
Detected that j uses these columns: x 
Finding groups using forderv ... 0.000sec 
Finding group sizes from the positions (can be avoided to save RAM) ... 0.000sec 
lapply optimization is on, j unchanged as 'list(max(x))'
GForce optimized j to 'list(gmax(x))'
Making each group and running j (GForce TRUE) ... 0.080sec
```

timings:

```
Unit: milliseconds
   expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
 mtd1() 323.3229 323.3229 323.3229 323.3229 323.3229 323.3229     1
 mtd2() 249.8188 249.8188 249.8188 249.8188 249.8188 249.8188     1
 mtd3() 479.5279 479.5279 479.5279 479.5279 479.5279 479.5279     1
```

data:

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1e7
m <- 10
DT = data.table(
    id=sample(1:m, n/m, replace=TRUE),
    date=sample(seq(Sys.Date(), by="-1 day", length.out=1000), n, replace=TRUE),
    x=runif(n))
window1 <- Sys.Date() - 50
window2 <- Sys.Date() - 150
window3 <- Sys.Date() - 550
DT[, date := as.IDate(date)]
setorder(DT, id, date)
DT1 <- copy(DT)
DT2 <- copy(DT)
DT3 <- copy(DT)
```